# BigQuery - query for metadata like 'last modified'

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to query for tables details in BigQuery? What do I mean? Running query like

```
SELECT * FROM region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

I get the name of the billing project, data set name, table name, table type, if is insertable, typed, and creation time. However, looking into the details tab in the BQ console, I can find table size, last modified, number of rows, partitioned by, and so on. Is there any way to query for those metadata as well?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the metadata by exporting BigQuery usage logs.

Setup logs export using Cloud Logging. See [creating a sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#creating_sink) for a more detailed take.

1. Open Logging
2. Click Logs Router
3. Click Create Sink
4. Enter "Sink Name"
5. For "Sink service" choose "BigQuery dataset"
6. Select your BigQuery dataset to monitor
7. Create sink

When the sink is created, all operations to be executed will store data usage logs in table "cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_YYYYMMDD" and activity logs in table "cloudaudit_googleapis_com_activity_YYYYMMDD" under the BigQuery dataset you selected in your sink. Keep in mind that you can only track the usage starting at the date when you set up the logs export tables.

**Created logging tables:**

[image]

Using this simple query I checked the latest update date of my table:

```
SELECT  
JSON_EXTRACT(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson, "$.tableChange.table.updateTime") as lastUpdate
FROM `project_id.dataset.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_activity*`
where protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY lastUpdate DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Query Output:**

[image]

See [more BigQuery logging query examples](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs#querying_exported_logs) and you can refer to the [metadata json structure](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/BigQueryAuditMetadata) to have an idea on what details you can pull on your tables.

---

**EDIT 20210923:**

Another option is to query __*TABLES__* it will return:

- project_id
- dataset_id
- table_id
- creation_time
- last_modified_time
- row_count
- size_bytes

See query:

```
SELECT * FROM `projec_id.dataset_id.__TABLES__` LIMIT 100
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I am appreciating your answer. This is however not useful for me. I would rather have something that allows querying through all tables in the billing project, not only the set specified. Also, I do not have permission to create a sink in this project. In relational databases, you can do it simply by the query.

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec I updated my answer to include an alternative solution. If you will only be needing the following information, then data from `___TABLES___` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` should suffice. But if more metadata is needed, using the logging method will be better.

Comment: I have clicked 'solved', though the solution doesn't work in the project I want to analyze. It however works pretty well in the other project that I have access to. So, the rest is a matter of approvals within the company I am working for.